# Regex: Find a word starts with one plus sign but not with two plus signs

Tags: regex

I lost a hope to find a solution by myself..

I need a regex to find a word(w) in a text which start with  plus sign (+), but ignore words which start with 2 or more plus signs,

i.e. in string

```
"+aaa +bbb ++ccc ddd eee+ fff++ +ggg hhh"
```

it should find

```
"aaa, bbb, ggg"
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: Which language/tool do you use? (Basically - does it support look-behinds?)

Comment: I am using java (Java 8)

Answer (score 2):

You can use following regex:

```
(?:\s|^)\+(\w+)
```

Demo : https://regex101.com/r/nU3oH3/4

Comment: works great, but I forgot to mention I need to find the following word as well "+c++"

Comment: @DimaK (?:\s|^)\+(\w+\+*) try this

Comment: @DimaK So what's the logic behind that words?

Comment: @Kasravand I'm finding words with leading one plus sign, for broad match search queries

Answer (score 1):

This would find the three matches:

```
(^|[^\+])\+(\w+)
```

fiddle: https://regex101.com/r/vD6iQ4/2

Comment: This will match words that have `+` within themselves!

Comment: I don't follow, a `+` would not be part of a word.

Comment: but `\w` matches `[^\+]`, so you could find, for instance, `b+ba`.

Comment: Hm, yes, but it does capture `ba` correctly. Depends on the definition of a word. Here: any consecutive letters preceded by a `+` but not multiple `+`. As in `bed+breakfast`...

Answer (score 1):

```
(^|\s+)\+(\w+)
```

https://regex101.com/r/bR1yF7/2

```
MATCH 1
1.  [0-0]   ``
2.  [1-4]   `aaa`
MATCH 2
1.  [4-5]   ` `
2.  [6-9]   `bbb`
MATCH 3
1.  [30-31] ` `
2.  [32-35] `ggg
```